# Create Dictionary out of for loops

Tags: python, dictionary, beautifulsoup, xgoogle

I would like to build a dictionary out of iterating over two different for loops:

My code is:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from xgoogle.search import GoogleSearch, SearchError

try:
    gs = GoogleSearch("search query")
    gs.results_per_page = 50
    results = gs.get_results()

    for res in results:
        print res.title.encode("utf8")
        print res.url.encode("utf8")
        print
except SearchError, e:
    print "Search failed: %s" % e
```

This code outputs a title and a url for each page found

I would like to get the following output

```
{title1:url1, title50,url50}
```

What would be a succint way to resolve this?

Thanks!

Comment: where are title1, title50,url50 coming from?

Comment: What is it that you want? Just create a new dict and add the titles and urls inside of the for loop, after your third print: `results[res.title] = res.url`?

Comment: Very fast responses! As @Others mentioned I am looking for {title1:url1, ... title50:url50}. It was not so clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want multiple values you need a container, if you have repeating keys you need a [collections.defaultdict](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) or [dict.setdefault](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/dictionary_setdefault.htm):

```
from collections import defaultdict
d = defaultdict(list)
try:
    gs = GoogleSearch("search query")
    gs.results_per_page = 50
    results = gs.get_results()

    for res in results:
        t = res.title.encode("utf8")
        u = res.url.encode("utf8")
        d[?].extend([t,u]) # not sure what key should be
except SearchError, e:
    print "Search failed: %s" % e
```

I am not exactly sure what the key is supposed to be but the logic will be the same.

If your expected output is in fact incorrect and you just want to pair each key `t` with a single  value just use a normal dict:

```
d = {}

try:
    gs = GoogleSearch("search query")
    gs.results_per_page = 50
    results = gs.get_results()

    for res in results:
        t = res.title.encode("utf8")
        u = res.url.encode("utf8")
        d[t] = u
except SearchError, e:
    print "Search failed: %s" % e
```

Comment: I think he wants the key to be the title, and the value to be the url.

Comment: @MarkusMeskanen, the OP's example is not a dict of single key/value pairings so it is not totally clear what exactly is  what

Comment: @PadraicCunningham I think he intended to write `{title1:url1, ... title50:url50}` since that makes a lot more sense.

Comment: @Others, it makes more sense but that does not necessarily mean it is right

Comment: Very fast responses! As @Others mentioned I am looking for {title1:url1, ... title50:url50}. It was not so clear.

Comment: @Diego, if you have single key/value pairings use the second.

Comment: Thank you @PadraicCunningham !!! Beautiful and succint solution. I appreciate the patience with a newbie.